# Add parameter to function php in option query mongo?

Tags: php, mongodb, aggregation-framework

My mongoDB have field: $creatime, I want add field to function php.
How do it?

```
$ops = array(
  array('$match' => $query),
  array('$addFields' => array('date_code' => functionPHP('$create_time'))),
);

$results = $col->aggregate($ops,array('cursor' => array('batchSize' => 200)));
```

Comment: what's the trouble here? what is `functionPHP`?

Comment: I want push value $create_time to functionPHP. I expected it's value in Doccument, but it return a string "$create_time".